# Count controlled Loops. Input 2 digits and find the Sum

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop, do-while

How do we solve this question? I am lost on how to start this? Thanks!:

Write algorithm and implement in python that will generate 2 1-digit numbers. The digit must be in the range 0 to 9 inclusive, and then add them together. Before displaying this sum, prompt user to guess this sum and get this input. All values will be integer values.

If the value inputted equals the sum display "Correct" otherwise display "Incorrect".

Also display the 2 digits generated and sum.

Then prompt the user to repeat (Y for Yes or N for No). If user enter Y (or y), repeat the process again. If user enter N (or n), terminate the process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: are you conducting a test? :P